# How to Apply OpenFileDialog Function to a WebApplication

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, openfiledialog

I am devoloping a Web Application, in which one Page has some neccessity that User should select any folder in the System and for ex if he selects ex:D:\xyz, then this Path should be Saved in Database, I have written the Code for Storing in to Database and Remaining Every thing. But actually i think that if it is like a Browse Button click function to select the Folder, what i have made is, as i dont know how to make it in Web Application simply i used a textbox to be able to user to type the Path. Can, any one help me how to apply the Open File Dialog Functionality in a Web Page?

Thanks in Advance,

Regards
Kalyan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ASP.Net Control to select folders.

As a simple workaround you could use the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx)-Control to let the user select a file and you can [save the folder of that file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename%28VS.90%29.aspx). But that would work only in IE because other browsers don't post the full file-path but only the file-name(security restrictions).

Edit: As Ben mentioned that doesn't work in IE>7 either:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx (section `File Upload Control`)

Comment: IE8 doesn't give the path either, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Add windows openfile dialog reference toweb application by righ click on solution explore project name add reference system.windows.forms
then follow this coding style here i have given `VB` sample code you can convert this to `C#` if your facing any problem tell me.

**VB Code**

```
   Import system.threading

   Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles btnUpload.Click

    Dim objThread As New Thread(AddressOf FnOpenFileDialog)
    objThread.IsBackground = True
    objThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    objThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub FnOpenFileDialog()
    Dim openfile As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    'openfile.InitializeLifetimeService()
    'openfile.Filter = String.Format("Image file (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*")
    openfile.Filter = String.Format("Image file (*.jpg)|*.jpg")
    openfile.Multiselect = True
    openfile.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there risks disadvantages to this approach? It would seem on the face of things to be stepping outside of the browser sandbox?

Comment: Yes after hosting its not working because this is windows application control you can go for html or asp fileupload controller if ur facing any problem feel free to contact

Answer (score 1):

For Web Application:

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(file1);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" +"Filename"+".ext"+ "\"");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = file.Extension.ToLower();
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Is the user selecting a file or a folder?
- Is the location on the server, or on his local computer?
- Are you trying to upload something, or download something, or just want the path?

If you want the path of a server file or folder, you have to get the server to give a list of possible folders to choose from.

If you just want the path of a local file, you cannot do this from a web application.

The easiest solution is to tell the user to browse in Explorer and copy the path, to paste in your dialog.

Comment: I just want to get the Path of the Folder which the User Opens through the Open Dialog, and i have to save the same path to the Database, right now i am providing a textbox to user to simply type the Path he want's in his local computer

Comment: You cannot do this from a web application, sorry. It's considered a security risk.