# OpenFileDialog in Webform Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I tried to use `OpenFileDialog()` control inside my Webform Application but it's not working.

I tried this coding but it gave me error :
**System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog** Not defined

```
Private Sub FnOpenFileDialog()
    Dim openfile As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    openfile.Filter = String.Format("Image file (*.jpg)|*.jpg")
    openfile.Multiselect = True
    openfile.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpload_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.PreRender
    Dim objThread As New Thread(AddressOf FnOpenFileDialog)
    objThread.IsBackground = True
    objThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    objThread.Start()
End Sub
```

Or is there any way on how to do it? I don't want to use `FileUpload` control because it shows **textbox + button**. I only want to show the `Button()` control.

I refer to this website [How to Apply OpenFileDialog Function to a WebApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272902/how-to-apply-openfiledialog-function-to-a-webapplication)

Answer (score 1):

In a ASP.NET web application, the VB code is run on the *web server*. So even if you would succeed in using `OpenFileDialog` that would result in the dialog being showed on the server, not in the browser.

JavaScript won't help you either, as the browswer sandbox in which JavaScripts run doesn't allow access to the file system (which is good from a security perspective). You simply have to accept that you need to work with the file upload control. You might be able to customize the appearance a bit by applying styles through css.

Comment: I guess that's the only way. By the way thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML input file ,as follow:

```
 <input id="File1" type="file" />
```